# How can I access Istio APIs?

Tags: rest, go, kubernetes, istio

I have created route rule using command line `istioctl create -f file.yaml`. I want to achieve same from custom GO code. Is there an Istio API to create route rules?

Comment: The type definitions here that Istio uses (generated from the .proto file) are here - https://github.com/istio/api/blob/master/routing/v1alpha2/

I'm not too sure if they are what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for the way to achieve istioctl operations using istio apis. I found that route rule can be created using `curl -X POST -d @test2.json -H "Content-Type: application/json"  http://localhost:8001/apis/config.istio.io/v1alpha2/namespaces/default/routerules`.  In the same way is it possible to inject sidecars into pod using an api?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/istio/client-go is the one you are looking for.